# Get Month name and count(*) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to dispaly Month wise data with count. So I have startdate and enddate. In between i need to show month and count.
Example: I have a table having salary details.

```
    Salary   createddate
--------------------------------
    10,000   1/jan/2017
    10,000   1/jan/2017
    10,000   1/jan/2017
    10,000   1/jan/2017
    10,000   1/jan/2017

    10,000   1/dec/2016
    10,000   1/dec/2016
    10,000   1/dec/2016
    10,000   1/dec/2016

    10,000   1/nov/2016
    10,000   1/nov/2016
    10,000   1/nov/2016
    10,000   1/nov/2016
```

So i need to display

```
   Month     count
----------------------------
    January    5
    Dec        4
    Nov        4
```

I have `startdate is 1/nov/2016  and end date  1/jan/2017` . I want to search monthname and count(salary) in between these two dates.
start and end date can be last year/4 years back also.

```
If i dont have data for mentioned dates, i should get month name with count as 0.
```

Please help me to find this

Comment: is the createdate field an actual date field, or a char?

Comment: created date is date field. but i'm passing  start and end date as varchar

Comment: Are grouping multiple years together? Or keeping them separate like jan 2015, jan 2016?

Comment: What you mean start and end date? the only example you have above is createdate

Comment: I want to search in between two dates. So It should display data in between passed start and end date.

Comment: @IMRUP have you tried my ans ? you can use where condition

Answer (score 1):

can you try this query ?

```
    select MONTHNAME(str_to_date(createddate,"%d/%b/%Y")),count(*) as count 
        from tableName  
where str_to_date(createddate,"%d/%b/%Y") between '2016-11-01' and '2017/01/01' 
        group by MONTHNAME(str_to_date(createddate,"%d/%b/%Y")),
     year(str_to_date(createddate,"%d/%b/%Y"))
```

Comment: can you try now ?

Comment: OP wants a query that will search between 2 dates and give the output provided in his example. As this has no where clause, there is no way to get the date range

Comment: @SaggingRufus he can add where condition in this query. I do not need to add it. just let him try this query

Comment: why even bother answering if you were only going to answer half the question?

Comment: If i dont have data for jan,dec and nov, I should get  month name with count(*) as 0 ... but im not getting that

Comment: @SaggingRufus letter i understand for where condition. is it ok now ?

Comment: @IMRUP  you should mention first it.

Comment: @SaggingRufus   I have common sense ok... If u can't answer why you are voting down ??

Comment: @ krishn patel   every time for every month there wont  be data right ?? i gave you just one example of salary...